# How can I identify a backedge from a BasicBlock in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I am writing an LLVM pass which analyzes and modifies the generated IR code. Is there a way to identify backedges, I mean to know if a successor of a BasicBlock is actually somewhere above it in path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

First, note that you need to distinguish between "every path to BB must pass through A", and "there is some path from A that might lead to BB".

I think that you're looking for the first situation - tell if the successor A of the basic block BB is a basic block that the execution must pass through to get to B.

When this situation happens, we say that "A dominates B". The interface to check for dominance is through the [DominatorTree](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html) class (add in in the getAnalysisUsage function of your pass. See the [writing an llvm pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#AU%3a%3aaddRequired) for an example).

Comment: Thanks Guy, I got the first case working by using DominatorTree. But now I also need the second case, that is, "there is some path from A that might to BB". Any idea what we can we use for that?

Comment: I am not sure if there's an LLVM method which does that (there isn't AFAIK) - but all the information is encoded in the list of basic blocks and their successors (AKA the function's call graph). It is actually a directed graph - so you can run a BFS from node A, and see if you can reach node B.